# regex for pattern before a certain word

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am having problems finding a right RegEx for recognizing the word before a certain word (but without the latter word). Below is the pattern, where W1 is dynamically asigned word.

```
   Set regExp = New RegExp 
    With regExp
        .Pattern = "\S* " + W1
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
```

This pattern works but i get the whole pattern. If I have such sentence :"Today is a sunny day" and W1 is set as "day", this pattern gives me "sunny day".

I would like to get just sunny, without the W1. Is this possible?

Thanks,m

Comment: Get it to do what? It's part of the pattern so do you just mean you want to be able to tell the parts from each other built into the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `W1` inside a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
.Pattern = "\S+(?= *" + W1 + ")"
```

Comment: Thanks...that's exactly what i wanted.